# Insert {{#link-to}} from Ember controller

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to add links programatically to an ul list, using jquery. But this links should go to a route of my application. So in my controller I had the following code:

```
$('#localidades').append('<li><a href="">' + title + '</a></li>');
```

But then I tried (without success of course), appending the handlebars form of links, like this:

```
$('#localidades').append('<li>{{#link-to "lang.index"}}' + title + '{{/link-to}}</li>');
```

How can this be done with Ember?

Thanks

Comment: did you look in the ember documentation?

Comment: Yes, found nothing. But I'm afraid I don't know how to search for such a specific question. Have you found something?

Comment: do all the li's go to the same route?

Comment: Yes and no, they should go to the same route, but with a different ID

Comment: then go with relative urls and remove the serverside code

Comment: Well, what would I capture an action of these links. I was thinking creating a span with an action on click, that was captured to the controller before making a route.transitioTo

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't use jquery for this. Maybe you should try to restructure your code so it doesn't rely on jquery.

Comment: You should model it as data, and render that data to the template. When you need a new link, add it to the data structure instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to go like that @locks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
href={{url}} // url being a function in you controller which returns the url
```

or

```
<p {{action "openUrl" model}}> </p>// which would trigger an action with a parameter so you could use ember transition functions to route
```

or

```
{{#link-to "name of route" parameter}}
```

plenty of options, there´s no need to use jquery